# Make View fill the gap in the middle but leaves space to its bottom siblings

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am kinda stump right now. I thought this is possible in Android XML.

I wanted to make a layout like this:

[image]

The problem is the small two elements that are side by side. When I make the view#2 to match the height, I am expecting that it will also respect the space of its other sibling. I was wrong but I now understand. When I set the layout_height of view#2 into match_parent, it occupies the remaining space and the view#3 and view#4 are put into bottom-most part and are no longer visible in screen.

I want it that view#2 will expand in the middle but still make some space for view#3 and view#4 and some elements below it and not to be pushed way down below.

Here is what I am doing right now:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".TaskActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textinput_layout_note_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_task"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/edittext_task_title_hint"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textinput_layout_note_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textinput_layout_note_title">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_todo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/edittext_task_content_hint"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textinput_layout_note_description"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_insert_note"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_content_add_black"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_choose_note"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_expand_note"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_open_in_new_black_24dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_expand_note"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've used LinearLayout combined with layout_weight but this gets more and more slow as I have some nested views that also requires weight. I wanted this to be done relatively.

Any ideas how I can achieve this layout?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted this to be done relatively.

`RelativeLayout` is not a magic bullet for performance.

> Any ideas how I can achieve this layout?

Try:

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textinput_layout_note_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        ...

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textinput_layout_note_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textinput_layout_note_title"
        android:layout_above="@+id/whatever_this_thing_is"/>

       ...

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/whatever_this_thing_is"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

       ...

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

(where the `...` bits are for the stuff you already have, removed to keep the listing shorter)

IOW:

- Anchor the top view to the top
- Anchor the bottom view to the bottom
- Anchor the middle view to be below the top and above the bottom, causing it to stretch to fill the intervening space

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, what if I have other views right below view 3 and 4. I've been trying mine lately but haven't got it to work. The best way I could think off is separate everything in two parts via linear layout. But I am intrigued if this is possible at all for RelativeLayout?

Comment: @NeonWarge: Off the cuff, have those be `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. Have the `LinearLayout` that I identified as `whatever_this_thing_is` have `android:layout_above` the new stuff. Everything else would stay as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach !, i haven't tried it in android studio, but it should do the trick.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewMiddle"
        android:layout_above="@id/viewBottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```